Error when trying to add Contextual Filter in Drupal Views
I am working on a Drupal Commerce project.I am running Drupal Version 9.5.11 and Commerce Version: 8.x-2.38 I am trying in my Product inner page to show other Products that have the same category with the Product on which I currently am on.
This should be a simple task but I can't understand what is going on. I create my View:

Now when I try to add my Contextual Filter on Product ID and I try to Provide Default Value and then choose Content ID from URL, and I click apply nothing is happening. The form is not being submitted.
I open my console log and I see this error every time I press the Apply button:

When I inspect the code of the form, I can find an element Profile Type, which is required, and display: none is applied to it. It has a small dropdown but without any options inside:

It's the first time I encounter something like this. I don't understand what is causing this problem and how to fix it. I don't even understand what the problem is. Why is there a required field with display: none and why is it required?
What should I do? Anyone encountered this or can help?

Did you get any errors when you open the views page?

Maybe this issue in the profile module's issue queue?
